# How to use same header.php file for all contentc php files in all directory

Tags: php, html, css

I have create header file like below.

```
<style type="text/css" >
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: #333; */}
.menu ul{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;}

.menu ul li{
    display: inline;}

.menu ul li a{
    float: left; text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    /* background-color: #333; */}
    /* 
.menu ul li a:visited{
    color: white;}*/

.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#0b75b2;}

}
</style>
<div class="menu" style="width:430px; height:43px; margin-left:420px; margin-right:auto;">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="image-gallery/index.php">Image Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="articles/index.php">Articles </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

so I have deference directories like, image-gallery, articles

file path :

```
www/websitename/index.php
```

I have include header.php to main index.php, it linked properly but when I include image-gallery's index file for that is not linked properly,

```
www/websitename/image-gallery/index.php
www/websitename/image-gallery/index.php
```

Comment: I would make all the anchor links relative to the document root as a start.

Comment: this is on main index.php
`<?php  include('header.php');  ?>`

other image-gallery directory index.php has like this .
`<?php  include('../header.php');  ?>`

Comment: The anchor `<a>` links in your header file, I meant.

Comment: Example: first `<a>` tag has an href "index.php". When the header file is loaded in e.g. **image-gallery/index.php** this first `<a>` tag will still address "index.php", which should (in that specific page) probably be "../index.php".

Comment: yes.. when user goes their first tag (Home) like still 'index.php' it is wrong, it should be '../index.php' I know that.. think we have more than 100pages , so we should change header for all.. I's not possible , their should be some method to generate o get server address create link properly and only using one header file for all directory ...

I want to know that method ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions, but the simplest method to implement is to have a define in a config.php file. The define, amongst other things, will specify the root file and root path

config.php

```
define('ROOT_URL', 'http://www.example.com/');
define('ROOT_PATH', '/var/www/html');
```

Then, in index.php, you'd have

```
include('config.php');
include('header.php');
```

or

```
include('../config.php');
include('../header.php');
```

and then, in header.php

```
<li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
```

---

There are many variations of this theme, the above is the simplest, but here are others.

Why this method? Because in config.php you can use

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'staging.example.com') {
        // One set of defines
   } else {
        // Assume live - user another set of defines
   }

and copy files from dev/staging/live without overwriting.

---

As opposed to "../" in hte includes, create a varaible "root_file" as "./" or "../" in each file. Then include($root_file . 'header.php'); do this in every script and you can also use for links.

---

If specifying hte complete URL, you may want to exclude the "http://" part and add the schem you're on, if you flick between https and http. Add the URL in code (or in a function the builds links)

---

You may want to store the details in a database (in which case you'll probably store the DB connection credentials in config instread

---

Finally, you could use $_SERVER[''] (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables, or `__FILE__` or `__ DIR__` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to determine where you are. Be careful as the REQUEST_URI may not accurately refect where the script is (if using .htaccess for rewrite rules), and SCRIPT_FILENAME/`__FILE__`/`__DIR__` may also lie if you're on symlinks. But if you know your server config, this is a very portable way of handling "where am I?".

So, plenty of options. Start simple and build up as your needs escillate.

Comment: <?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>
it was not display anything..
$ROOT_URL not working

Comment: Now ok .. 
constant("ROOT_URL")